# PowerPivot: How to make running total forumla based on date?

Tags: excel, powerpivot

I am looking for a way to count usage stats that show a zero in the metric column over a period of time.   For the 60 day event to trigger it should also have a zero in the 30 day event.  If the most recent month has more than a zero then it shouldn't show up for any of them. The goal is to have a 30-60 day view and total of how many IDs have not shown a metric greater than zero.

Sample data table:

[image: Sample data table]

The following shows how IDs in the table should add to the totals:

- ID 1: 30 and 60 totals (since it has zero for both months)
- ID 2: nothing
- ID 3: 30 day total (since it only has zero for the most recent month)
- ID 4: nothing

Comment: Can you simple create a new column on powerpivot when Metric = 0 then give 1 else 0 and sum that column?  YOU have the infomation at level of date?